# Simple string templating in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, string, templates, token

I have a bunch of database log messages containing references like `Invoice 45` or `Case 123` which I want to parse to output links to the appropriate invoice or case when displaying to the user.

These are fairly simple to parse with RegEx and replace with an action link using an ASCX display template, but is there a *right* way to do this? I imagine this means writing a parser to tokenise the string and prevent any potential circular references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML helper is probably a better fit - the parsing / display doesn't do anything that you could put in the ascx that isn't better handled in code.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd rather not instantiate a new RegEx object in each display template. Is it possible that circular references could lead to recursive replacements (aka catastrophic recursion)?

Comment: I'm not quite seeing where the risk of recursion is - isn't it just a simple regex on a string that returns multiple matches? Nothing in your example suggests recursion to me. Also, I wouldn't worry about the overhead of instantiating a regex - there are ways to share objects if you need to, but it's not likely to matter and finding a display template has a fair bit of overhead as well.

Comment: If you are worried about the overhead of instantiating objects separately each time the helper is called, an inline helper may be of use - that compiles to an anonymous method within the view, so should have access to any variables set in the main part of the view.

Comment: @Tom, I was thinking along the lines of supporting more complicated tokens, which could lead to potentially hazardous string, but in the end, I used simple RegEx matching and replacing.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the tip on using an inline helper. An external static helper would be even better, no?

Comment: There isn't much difference for most purposes - aside from variable scope and reusability they compile to the same thing.